# How extract apps from a iTunes backup file?

Tags: iphone, itunes, backup, time-machine, windows

I have recently restored my iPhone using the IPSW file but before this, I had made a full backup of my iPhone using iTunes.

Now when I restore the backup, it just brings icons of my app and needs to be downloaded and besides that, I had many files inside one of my file explorer apps(in my case it was 'offline' downloader and file explorer).

My question is how can I retrieve those files and apps? is it possible?

My OS is windows 10 and my Itunes is Version 12.10.3.1

Comment: In a comment on an answer below, you mention you wanted to "retrieve files that were stored in [an app]." If this is what you're referring to (and not retrieving the executable .ipa file itself) then you could just google and find a backup explorer. I've used iExplorer for this exact purpose, and it worked fine.

Comment: @At0mic, fortunately, when I redownloaded that app (which was in a waiting mode when I restored backup) somehow all my files were inside it :)

Answer (score 6):

iTunes hasn't saved or restored ipa files in a long time. Apple expect you to recover everything OTA [over the air] these days & assume you have a current online backup over iCloud.

This function change arrived with version 12.7 - http://osxdaily.com/2017/09/13/itunes-12-7-update-removes-app-store/

If you do already have an ipa of an app no longer available from the App Store, you can use [Apple Configurator 2](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/apple-configurator-2/id1037126344?mt=12) to restore it to the phone. There are other MDM solutions that allow tethered app installation as well if you really need that capability.

- https://www.groundctl.com/docs/425

Comment: unfortunately, I don't have an online backup but I have on in my pc. well, apps can be redownloaded although it takes time (with my internet speed). specifically, my question is how can retrieve files that were stored in file explorer app which in my case it was 'offline' a downloader and file explorer.

Comment: idk how that app works, but basically the app is online, that's where your backup will come from too. I know it's an abysmal failure of a working method [which will probably get this comment deleted], but I didn't design it. Apple have removed the user's ability to be in charge of their own destiny by removing their ability to keep **proper** local backups.

Comment: @NimaBahar On Windows we have had luck getting IPA files from old backups of windows filesystem data, but with the new iOS 12 I’m not sure that’s going to work - if the IPA are signed with expired certs this will fail and it’s not clear iTunes does IPA backup anyhow and you might need the apps to be current on the store - current for reinstall, not current for new purchase.

Comment: Tetsujin is correct - this has all moved to MDM. There are free MDM that require a lot of time invested to learn how it works or commercial offerings where they spent the time to learn how it works and take your money to save you that time.

Comment: @bmike - Thanks for the edits [& apologies for the slight rant in comments]  ;)

Comment: You nailed it, man. This answer is great.